# Defining a new input format

Tags: 7

I need to define a new input format programmatically, probably as part of my module's `hook_install()`.  I need to write code that duplicates the manual operations described on http://drupal.org/node/778976.

I have not been able to learn how to do this. Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: This edit has made the question more clear. Taking back my answer, because it's obviously not applicable here ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code from standard Drupal profile is your friend: http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/c5d6e6334fb7a71ecf1dbc7e06a7de8ad9547b27:/profiles/standard/standard.install#l14

```
  // Add text formats.
  $filtered_html_format = array(
    'format' => 'filtered_html',
    'name' => 'Filtered HTML',
    'weight' => 0,
    'filters' => array(
      // URL filter.
      'filter_url' => array(
        'weight' => 0,
        'status' => 1,
      ),
      // HTML filter.
      'filter_html' => array(
        'weight' => 1,
        'status' => 1,
      ),
      // Line break filter.
      'filter_autop' => array(
        'weight' => 2,
        'status' => 1,
      ),
      // HTML corrector filter.
      'filter_htmlcorrector' => array(
        'weight' => 10,
        'status' => 1,
      ),
    ),
  );
  $filtered_html_format = (object) $filtered_html_format;
  filter_format_save($filtered_html_format);
```

Enable permission for system roles ([code](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/c5d6e6334fb7a71ecf1dbc7e06a7de8ad9547b27:/profiles/standard/standard.install#l395)):

```
// Enable default permissions for system roles.
$filtered_html_permission = filter_permission_name($filtered_html_format);
user_role_grant_permissions(DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID, array($filtered_html_permission));
user_role_grant_permissions(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID, array($filtered_html_permission));
user_role_grant_permissions(variable_get('user_admin_role', 0), array($filtered_html_permission));
```

Comment: @GisleHannemyr answer was updated.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr `variable_get('user_admin_role', 0)`

Comment: Filter and input format are different things. Filter can be defined in your module with `hook_filter_info` and attached to any input format.